# Can you self-induce a derealization episode?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, perception, abnormal-psychology, consciousness

From [**The experimental induction of depersonalization (DP) and derealization (DR) in panic disorder and nonanxious subjects (Miller, et al., 1994)**](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8042962)

> DP and DR induction procedures were the following: staring at a dot on the wall, staring in a mirror, and **silent repetition of one's name.** (Miller et al., 1994)*.

If derealization can be induced by repeating ones own name, I'm wondering if repeating the phrase "I am me" causes derealization as well?

[Semantic satiation (also semantic saturation)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_satiation) is a psychological phenomenon in which repetition causes a word or phrase to temporarily lose meaning for the listener" or is it the state of hyper meta-cognition that makes everything seem foreign? Or maybe it's both?

### References

Miller, P. P., Brown, T. A., DiNardo, P. A., & Barlow, D. H. (1994). The experimental induction of depersonalization and derealization in panic disorder and nonanxious subjects. *Behaviour Research and Therapy, 32*(5), 511-519. doi: [10.1016/0005-7967(94)90138-4](https://doi.org/10.1016/0005-7967(94)90138-4) pmid: [8042962](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8042962)

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. This is an interesting question and hope an answer can be found